Plotting the I-V Characteristics of a Solar Panel for a Specified Irradiance and Temperature C++ project not working
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

const double q = 1.602e-19;
const double k = 8.617e-5;
const double Rs = 0.008 * 36;
const double Rsh = 1000 * 36;
const double Ns = 36;
const double I_sc = 3.8;
const double Voc = 21.1;
const double TR = 25;
const double a = 0.00065;
const double b = 0.08;
const double n = 2.1; 

double I_ph(double T, double G) {
    return (I_sc + (a * (T - 298.15))) * ( G / 1000.0);
}

double I_0(double T) {
    double exponent = q * (Voc + b * (T - 298.15)) / (n * k * T * Ns);
    double denominator = exp(exponent) - 1;

    return (I_sc + a * (T - 298.15)) / denominator;
}

double calc_I(double V, double T, double G) {

    double Vt = (k * (T + 273.15)) / q;

    return I_ph(T, G) - I_0(T) * (exp((q * (V + (V / Rs))) / (n * k * T * Vt)) - 1) - ((V + (V / Rs)) / Rsh);
}

double calculateVmax(double T) {
    double Vt = (k * (T + 273.15)) / q;
    return Voc - ((k * (T + 273.15)) / q) * log(I_sc / (I_sc + I_0(T)));
}

double newtonRaphson(double V, double T, double G) {
    const double epsilon = 1e-6; // Tolerance
    const double dx = 1e-6; // Step size for derivative

    double x0 = V;
    while (true) {
        double f = calc_I(x0, T, G) - V;
        double df = (calc_I(x0 + dx, T, G) - calc_I(x0, T, G)) / dx;
        double x1 = x0 - f / df;

cout << "x0: " << x0 << ", f: " << f << ", df: " << df << endl;

        // Check for convergence
        if (abs(x1 - x0) < epsilon) {
            return x1;
        }

        x0 = x1;
    }
}

int main() {
    ifstream file("data.csv");
    if (!file.is_open()) {
        cerr << "Failed to open file." << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    int numLines = 0;
    string line;
    while (getline(file, line)) {
        numLines++;
    }

    file.close();
    file.open("data.csv");

    const int numRows = numLines - 1;
    const int numCols = 3;
    string data[numRows][numCols];

    getline(file, line);
for (int i = 0; i < numRows; ++i) {
getline(file, line);
stringstream ss(line);
string item;
int col = 0;
while (getline(ss, item, ',')) {
if (col == 0) {
data[i][col++] = item;
ss.seekg(1, ios_base::cur);
} else {
data[i][col++] = item;
}
}
}
file.close();

    string time;
    cout << "Enter the time you want readings for (in the format of 0:00 AM/PM, KEEP THE SPACE): ";
    cin >> time;

    double T = 0.0;
    double G = 0.0;
    for (int m = 0; m < numRows; ++m) {
        if (data[m][0] == time) {
            G = stod(data[m][1]);
            T = stod(data[m][2]);
            break;
        }
    }

    double Vmax = calculateVmax(T);

    ofstream outFile("GraphData.txt");
    if (!outFile.is_open()) {
        cerr << "Failed to open output file." << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    double V_step = 1.0;
    for (double V = 0; V < Vmax; V += V_step) {
        double I = newtonRaphson(V, T, G);
 cout << "I: " << I << endl; // Print the calculated current
        outFile << V << " " << I << "\n";
    }
    outFile.close();

    ofstream gnuplotFile("plot_commands.gnu");
    if (gnuplotFile.is_open()) {
        gnuplotFile << "plot 'GraphData.txt' with lines title 'I-V Curve'\n";
        gnuplotFile.close();
        system("gnuplot -persist plot_commands.gnu");
    } else {
        cerr << "Error opening plot commands file.\n";
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

this is my code, it has no error in compiling at all but it gave no output whatsoever. the file that the values should be stored in is empty. this is the first time I learn to code so I do not have any background to understand complex problems, therefore couldn't debug the code.  maybe the problem is with the equations, I attached a photo of them as I may be have written them wrong. Lastly, indentations maybe wrong because I do not use vscode so it does not matter.
I tried to remove the extraction of T and G values part as it maybe the problem and set them to fixed values. also making the v-step larger and the tolerance for the newton-raphson. then I added these cout lines to see if there is some wrong values but still no output.

"this is the first time I learn to code so I do not have any background to understand complex problems" -- It really helps to be able to understand a problem before coding a solution to it. Don't jump in with so much code before you try to debug it. Start simple, then build up from there. Can you get #include <iostream> int main() { std::cout << "Enter the time you want readings for (in the format of 0:00 AM/PM, KEEP THE SPACE): "; } to give output? If not, ask about that. If so, keep building up piece by piece until you find a piece that does not work, and ask about that piece.

"Lastly, indentations maybe wrong because I do not use vscode so it does not matter." -- Indentation is for the humans reading the code. If there is ever going to be a human reading the code (such as the humans reading this question), then indentation does matter (for legibility).

FYI, indentation has nothing to do with the IDE.  I have written programs using the standard input that were indented correctly.  There are other editors and IDEs than VSCode.  I highly recommend using VS Community edition until you become more experienced, then you can switch back to VS Code.

Your title says you are having issues plotting values.  Create a static const array, put some values in there.  Plot those values.  You don't need all that functionality to plot values.  After you get the plotting working, restore the calculation functions.
